Eigenvectors of self-adjoint operator
As I'm studying quantum mechanics, it is said without any reasoning or proof, that a self-adjoint linear operator's eigenvectors make a basis for a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. I am aware of the spectral theorems for bounded and unbounded self-adjoint linear operators and see how they may suggest using the continuous "eigenvectors" corresponding to the continuous spectrum. So my question is: Is it true that only the discrete spectrum with its eigenvectors create a total orthogonal system or do we also need to incorporate the other types of spectra in some way? (I might add that this course I'm studying from isn't that math-oriented so they just say that eigenvalues are the solutions to $\hat{T}\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$ and that the set of eigenvalues IS the spectrum which only adds to my confusion.)

related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/821406/50583

See the section "Spectral subspaces and projection-valued measures" of the Wikipedia page on the spectral theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem. That is the more general version. Indeed, often a basis of eigenvectors doesn't exist, but there is an operator-valued measure that plays the role of $|x\rangle \langle x| dx$.

You need to consider non-point part of the spectrum, namely the continuous spectrum. Once you do that, you can consider the (generalised) eigenvalue equation on a bigger space than the Hilbert space. Then the spectral theorem holds on the bigger space, with real (generalised) eigenvalues. It is sometimes known as the nucluear spectral theorem. See the rigged Hilbert space formalism for this. See this answer and the comments as well: mathoverflow.net/a/126758/516900

In general for the operators seen in QM, the discrete spectrum is insufficient for the corresponding eigenvectors to span the space of interest. Not only do you need to include all eigenvalues but the whole spectrum. The fact that the discrete spectrum alone is not enough is clear because a discrete set of eigenvalues has a countable number of eigenvectors. Meanwhile, for variables that take continuous values, you'd need a continuum (uncountable) of eigenvectors. You couldn't map to such a space with a countable set of eigenvectors.
Functional analysis of unbounded operators, the field which handles this precisely, is very rarely taught in physics. I think this is mostly because

Professors with a physics background usually don't know it. The right person to ask is a mathematical physicist
A lot of additional understanding is necessary and for almost all applications you can handle things naively, in analogy with how eigenvalues and eigenvectors work for finite-dimensional linear operators (matrices).

You can decide what your goals are in terms of precision vs being able to solve applications sooner. If you want just a bit of an intro into how things work I recommend trying to understand how to construct a self-adjoint operator for some simpler examples. I searched around a bit and found a PDF that looks pretty solid. You might be able to skip to the momentum operator example in the middle first, and then reference the previous text depending on what you need:
https://rohankulkarni.me/project/case_study_momentum/case_study_momentum.pdf
If you want to be able to understand the most work in physics per unit time spent, I'd recommend having a very solid understanding of eigenvalues/vectors with matrices first of all, and then coming back to functional analysis later if you like, depending on which specific questions you want to focus on. One thing I can say though: Some people have a hope that the precision of functional analysis will resolve some of the ambiguities inherent in the QM formalism, for example with measurement. This is not the case. It mostly takes the already-pretty-functional part of QM and puts it on even more solid footing. Measurement remains ill-defined.

"Meanwhile, for variables that take continuous values, you'd need a continuum (uncountable) of eigenvectors. You couldn't map to such a space with a countable set of eigenvectors.". How is it possible then you can have a total orthonormal basis which is countable in a function Hilbert space? For example Legendre or Hermite polynomials.

There you have countably many parameters to specify a state: a state is a set of coefficients that specify a particular polynomial. But in quantum mechanics, a state usually has uncountably many parameters, as it's a function (the wave function, expressed in that basis). The components of $|\psi\rangle$ in the position basis are the values $\psi(x) \forall x$.
